# Creating a AWS WorkMail Lambda invoke permission in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

When I create a Lambda::Permission resource in Cloudformation I have an issue with validating the principal. Currently I have it set to use the !Sub function and that's not a valid principal according to CloudFormation. Does any one have any experience with creating a workmail invoke permission?

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:
  WorkmailInvokePermission:
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Permission'
    Properties:
      Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
      FunctionName: arn:aws:<region>:<function_arn>
      Principal: !Sub workmail.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com
Outputs: {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it was a pretty simple, the problem was I was in a region where Workmail wasn't actually available so it ended up creating an error.